# Speed up Windows Server 2016 with slow system disk & fast auxiliary disk

Tags: windows, azure, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter running on Azure. To keep costs low we can't use one of the SSD backed systems. However, our plan does include a "temporary" SSD disk. That disk cannot be used for persistent data, it will be erased when stopping the VM.

This means I have a slow system disk (C:) and a fast auxiliary disk that can be used for temporary data (D:).

**How can I get the best performance out of the system without switching to a more expensive plan?**

I've already updated the `TMP` and `TEMP` environment variables to point to a location on D:, but maybe there are other improvements?

Comment: care to share what workload you are running and trying to enhance performance for?

Comment: @CtrlDot It will be used as a CI server that builds .NET projects. The build is already configured to run on the SSD though.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do in terms of speeding up the system disk if you're not willing to use SSDs, but you can make things a lot better for the data disks without it. All you have to do is attach several disks to your VM and create a storage pool (aka software raid). Each standard disk in Azure delivers 500IOPS of performance and up to 60MB/s so two disks in a raid will give you 1000IOPS and 120MB/s and so on if you continue to stack up more disks.

For each CPU core, you may have up to 2 disks. i.e 4 Cores VM supports 8